# Implementing UPPER,TRIM and REPLACE in Apache Pig

Tags: replace, apache-pig, trim, uppercase

I am quiet new to pig environment. I have tried to implement my pig script file in two ways.

I.

```
data = LOAD 'sample2.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as(campaign_id:chararray,date:chararray,time:chararray,display_site:chararray,placement:chararray,was_clicked:int,cpc:int,keyword:chararray);

distinct_data = DISTINCT data;

val = foreach distinct_data generate campaign_id,date,time,UPPER(keyword),display_site,placement,was_clicked,cpc;

val1 = foreach val generate campaign_id,date,time,TRIM(keyword),display_site,placement,was_clicked,cpc;

val2 = foreach val1 generate campaign_id,REPLACE(date, '-', '/'),time,keyword,display_site,placement,was_clicked,cpc;

dump val2;
```

i get error:

> 2016-09-29 02:45:40,826 INFO org.apache.pig.Main: Apache Pig version
>   0.10.0-cdh4.2.1 (rexported) compiled Apr 22 2013, 12:04:54 2016-09-29 02:45:40,827 INFO org.apache.pig.Main: Logging error messages to:
>   /home/training/training_materials/analyst/exercises/pig_etl/pig_1475131540824.log
>   2016-09-29 02:45:42,371 ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt: ERROR
>   1025:   Invalid field
>   projection. Projected field [keyword] does not exist in schema:
>   campaign_id:chararray,date:chararray,time:chararray,org.apache.pig.builtin.upper_keyword_12:chararray,display_site:chararray,placement:chararray,was_clicked:int,cpc:int.
>   Details at logfile: /home/hduser/pig_etl/pig_1475131540824.log

But When i integrate the UPPER,TRIM and REPLACE in one statement then it works:

II.

```
data = LOAD 'sample2.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as(campaign_id:chararray,date:chararray,time:chararray,display_site:chararray,placement:chararray,was_clicked:int,cpc:int,keyword:chararray);

distinct_data = DISTINCT data;

val = foreach distinct_data generate campaign_id,REPLACE(date, '-', '/'),time,TRIM(UPPER(keyword)),display_site,placement,was_clicked,cpc;
dump val;
```

So, I just want someone to explain me that why I. method didn't work and what is the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are applying `TRIM` in `val1` there is nothing called "`keyword`" in `val`.

Note when you are applying any Function **use alias** so that error u can avoid..

or before creating a new relation it is always good to use **`describe`** so that the schema is clear to u..

Solution will be:

```
data = LOAD 'sample2.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as(campaign_id:chararray,date:chararray,time:chararray,display_site:chararray,placement:chararray,was_clicked:int,cpc:int,keyword:chararray);

distinct_data = DISTINCT data;

val = foreach distinct_data generate campaign_id,date,time,UPPER(keyword) as keyword,display_site,placement,was_clicked,cpc;

val1 = foreach val generate campaign_id,date,time,TRIM(keyword) as keyword,display_site,placement,was_clicked,cpc;

val2 = foreach val1 generate campaign_id,REPLACE(date, '-', '/') as date,time,keyword,display_site,placement,was_clicked,cpc;

dump val2;
```

Comment: thanks @ankur and great advice i'll definitely use describe from now on.